# compile error combining CUDA and Boost special functions

Tags: boost, cuda

This seems to be a recurring issue.

I use a combination of CUDA and Boost libraries. The works fine e.g. for some Boost libraries. If I try to include `boost/math/special_functions.hpp`, I get errors like:

> argument of type "_*v1di" is incompatible with parameter of type
>   "*_attribute((vector_size(8))) long"

Any advice would be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NVCC support in boost is still unstable. Most heavy TMP based code are susceptible to failure. As a maintainer of the NVCC support in boost, i urge you to report the error to the Boost SVN Trac so we can handle it

Comment: +1 I was unaware of any effort on the side of Boost. Interesting.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer to solve this specific problem, but a more general one. I'm assuming here you use NVCC to compile your code which includes the Boost header. Passing heavily templated code through NVCC sometimes causes problems. Make sure you're using the very latest version of NVCC. Template support keeps improving and you might just get lucky with an update.

Otherwise, you might want to devise a way to split your code into a part using Boost which won't need to go through NVCC and CUDA specific code which does.